# What does 你们已经干得够多了 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read an opinion piece regarding the US response to the coronavirus: [哥伦比亚大学教授质问美国高官：用谎言攻击中国可能导致冲突，“你们没有羞耻感吗？”](https://news.sina.com.cn/c/2020-05-07/doc-iirczymk0229155.shtml) (7 May 2020).  I don't understand one part:

> 特朗普先生、蓬佩奥先生，你们收到了很多警告。到目前为止，美国人民还没有完全认清你们的鲁莽。**你们已经干得够多了**。你们没有羞耻感吗？

My translation:

> Mr. Trump, Mr. Pompeo, you received many warnings.  Until now, the American people have still not completely recognized your recklessness.  **You already 干得够多了 (?)**.  Do you have no sense of shame?

It seems to mean something like "done enough work", which doesn't make sense here.  I don't really understand.

**Question**: What does 你们已经干得够多了 mean?

Comment: It is meant to be a sarcasm. A back-handed compliment.

Comment: It means something like, "you have done enough damage already"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

特朗普先生、蓬佩奥先生，你们收到了很多警告。
Mr Trump, Mr Pompeo, you received a lot of warnings.
到目前为止，
up to now,
美国人民还没有完全认清你们的鲁莽。
the American people have not fully realized the extent of your recklessness.
你们已经干得够多了。
haven't you already been reckless enough?
你们没有羞耻感吗？
Shouldn't you (both) feel ashamed?

特朗普: 迈克，请允许我回答。
Trump: Allow me to answer that, Mike.
特朗普: 小姐，情况是这样，要感到羞耻，你需要良心，所以不，我们不感到羞耻。华盛顿没有羞耻心！
Trump: The thing is honey, to feel ashamed, ya gotta have a conscience, so no, we don't feel ashamed. Ain't no shame in Washington!

Answer (score 1):

You have done so many (trash) things
"你干的事" "他干的事" has irony meaning.
it means "awful things you have done" ,"Do bad things behind your back" not just "things" or "work".
"你瞧瞧你干的好事" look what you have done.(blame)

Answer (score 1):

It's meant to be sarcastic, as in "Haven't you done ENOUGH already?!"

Indeed, the original article in English was:

> There was plenty of warning, Messrs. Trump and Pompeo. To this moment, Americans have not fully gauged your recklessness. You have done enough. Have you no shame?

https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/05/opinions/trumps-anti-china-theory-implodes-sachs/index.html